# nested for loop to build a "0" pyramid

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

```
for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0, 7 - i):
        print(" ", end = "")
    for k in range(0, 2 * i + 1):
        print("0", end = "")
    print(" ")
```

I saw this code online to build a pyramid contains "0", I'm confused on why do I need to pint(" ") at the very bottom for the first loop?

Comment: `print("0", end = "")` this will continue next printing value on same line. `print(" ")` this will get it to new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `print` with `end=""` to build the lines character by character without getting to a new line.

To build the pyramid, you need to skip to the next line after a line of zeros, thus the `print(" ")` that has a `end='\n'` parameter by default

output without the last print:

```
       0      000     00000    0000000   000000000  00000000000 0000000000000
```

Here is a modification of the code to show you where the separators are:

```
for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0, 7 - i):
        print(" ", end = "-")
    for k in range(0, 2 * i + 1):
        print("0", end = "+")
    print("", end='=\n')
```

output:

```
 - - - - - - -0+=
 - - - - - -0+0+0+=
 - - - - -0+0+0+0+0+=
 - - - -0+0+0+0+0+0+0+=
 - - -0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+=
 - -0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+=
 -0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+=
```

Here is a shorter alternative to the initial code to build the lines directly with a single loop:

```
n=7
for i in range(n):
    print(' '*(n-i)+'0'*(2*i+1))
```

output:

```
       0
      000
     00000
    0000000
   000000000
  00000000000
 0000000000000
```